# Expanding collapse tree on a Google Account webpage using selenium webserver

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently working on an automation project that go into my google account and perform certain tasks. I am currently at a point where I need to expand a collapse tree on the webpage, the code for the tree is as follow:

```
<div class="gwt-PopupPanel" style="visibility: visible; overflow: visible; position: absolute; left: 308px; top: 157px;">

    <div class="popupContent">
       <div>
         <div class="orgTreeDropDown-panel gux-dropdown-c">
           <div class="orgTreeDropDown-treePanel" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; width: 20em; height: 40ex;">
             <div style="position: relative;">
              <div class="gwt-FastTree" style="position: relative;" role="tree">
               <div class=" selection-bar" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; width: 223px; height: 34px; top: 240px; left: 20px; display: none;" focus="false" role="treeitem" aria-hidden="true">
                 <input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" type="text">
               </div>
               <div class="gwt-FastTreeItem" style="margin: 0px;">
                <div class=" closed">
                 <div class="treeItemContent">
                  <div class="ELWINOB-Zg-a orgTree-item" tabindex="-1">
                   <input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" type="text">
                    <table class="ELWINOB-Zg-i" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

This code is not the full code for the tree, just for the first item.

Here's how it look on the webpage:[Tree representation as shown on Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFrZm.png)

The problem is google built this element with another on top of it so clicking anywhere on the node will select the element item there instead of expanding it. To expand, it needs to click on the arrow symbol next to the item.

My thinking process here is if I can find the actual element that holds the root node to expand the tree than clicking anywhere wouldn't matter

Here's the line of code I use to expand the root node:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='closed']")).click()`;

But I keep encountering an error: Unable to locate element: .//*[@class='closed']

I'm like 90% sure my xpath is directing to the right place so I'm stuck and have no clue what to do.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing this for personal or business google account ? How do you get to this page after logging into your google account ? I need to see the page to help you.

Comment: This is a business account, and you can get to this page by clicking on the google app icon on the top right then admin then devices then device management. Again this is a business account so I'm not sure if a regular account will have this option.

Comment: @VuTran - You'll have to share the link. Do you have a dummy login you can share ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a dummy login, I only have the business one and I'm not allow to share that one.